# Merging two dataframes by datetime with a different structure in R

Tags: r, merge

I would like to merge dataframe 1 with 2, but I don´t know how because of the different structure. In Dataframe 1 the date is in one column with the day and time, in Dataframe 2 there are three columns with a time span.

```
Dataframe 1
datetime               PM
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 2017-05-17 07:00:26 2.5  
 2 2017-05-17 08:00:26 4.17 
 3 2017-05-17 09:00:26 0.333
 4 2017-05-17 10:00:26 0    
 5 2017-05-17 11:00:26 0    
 6 2017-05-17 12:00:26 0    
 7 2017-05-17 13:00:26 0    
 8 2017-05-17 14:00:26 0    
 9 2017-05-17 15:00:26 0    
10 2017-05-17 16:00:26 0    
11 2017-05-17 17:00:27 0    
12 2017-05-17 18:00:27 0    
13 2017-05-17 19:00:27 0.5  
14 2017-05-17 20:00:27 1.67 
15 2017-05-17 21:00:27 2    
16 2017-05-17 22:00:27 2.67 

Dataframe 2
DATE                SHIP        In    Out     PAX
  <dttm>              <chr>       <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 2017-05-17 00:00:00 Rotterdam   07:00 17:00  1404
2 2017-05-17 00:00:00 Deutschland 08:00 14:00   600
3 2017-05-18 00:00:00 Serenade    07:00 17:00  2200
4 2017-05-18 00:00:00 AIDAsol     11:00 20:00  2194
5 2017-05-19 00:00:00 Marco Polo  07:30 15:00   800
6 2017-05-21 00:00:00 Balmoral    07:30 16:00  2000

Expected result
datetime    PM1 Shipname1   ShipPAX1    Shipname2   ShipPAX2 
17.5.17 7:00    5,0 Rotterdam   1404,00 Deutschland 
17.5.17 8:00    4,0 Rotterdam   1404,00 Deutschland 600,00
17.5.17 9:00    1,0 Rotterdam   1404,00 Deutschland 600,00
17.5.17 10:00   1,0 Rotterdam   1404,00 Deutschland 600,00
17.5.17 11:00   2,0 Rotterdam   1404,00 Deutschland 600,00
17.5.17 12:00   5,0 Rotterdam   1404,00 Deutschland 600,00
17.5.17 13:00   3,0 Rotterdam   1404,00 Deutschland 600,00
17.5.17 14:00   6,0 Rotterdam   1404,00 Deutschland 600,00
17.5.17 15:00   2,0 Rotterdam   1404,00 Deutschland NA
17.5.17 16:00   3,0 Rotterdam   1404,00 Deutschland NA
17.5.17 17:00   4,0 Rotterdam   1404,00 NA  NA
17.5.17 18:00   8,0 NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: `unite` these columns and `merge` perhaps or split the date in df1 and merge by date.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Seeing your code, even if it doesn't fully work, can help explain the thinking behind this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `data.table` solution..

**sample data**

```
library( data.table)
#first create some good sample data
#  I added T between date and time, to read it in as one string/column automatically
DT1 <- fread("datetime    PM1   
             17.5.17T7:00    5,0
             17.5.17T8:00    4,0
             17.5.17T9:00    1,0
             17.5.17T10:00   1,0
             17.5.17T11:00   2,0
             17.5.17T12:00   5,0
             17.5.17T13:00   3,0
             17.5.17T14:00   6,0
             17.5.17T15:00   2,0
             17.5.17T16:00   3,0
             17.5.17T17:00   4,0
             17.5.17T18:00   8,0")

DT2 <- fread("DATE    SHIP    In  Out PAX
             17.5.17T0:00    Rotterdam   07:00   17:00   1404,00
             17.5.17T0:00    Deutschland 08:00   14:00   600,00
             ")

#now create real POSIXct dates
DT1[, datetime := as.POSIXct( datetime, format = "%d.%m.%yT%H:%M") ]
DT2[, DATE := as.POSIXct( DATE, format = "%d.%m.%yT%H:%M") ]

#set start and end date as POSIXct
DT2[, In  := as.POSIXct( paste0( as.IDate(DATE), "T", In  ), format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M") ] 
DT2[, Out := as.POSIXct( paste0( as.IDate(DATE), "T", Out ), format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M") ]
```

**code**

```
#use data.table::foverlaps to join on date ranges
ans <- DT2[ DT1, on = .( In <= datetime, Out >= datetime ) ]
#and cast to wide format, using SHIP as columnname, and PAX as value
dcast( ans, In + PM1 ~ SHIP, value.var = "PAX" )
#                  In PM1   NA Deutschland Rotterdam
#  1: 2017-05-17 07:00:00 5,0 <NA>        <NA>   1404,00
#  2: 2017-05-17 08:00:00 4,0 <NA>      600,00   1404,00
#  3: 2017-05-17 09:00:00 1,0 <NA>      600,00   1404,00
#  4: 2017-05-17 10:00:00 1,0 <NA>      600,00   1404,00
#  5: 2017-05-17 11:00:00 2,0 <NA>      600,00   1404,00
#  6: 2017-05-17 12:00:00 5,0 <NA>      600,00   1404,00
#  7: 2017-05-17 13:00:00 3,0 <NA>      600,00   1404,00
#  8: 2017-05-17 14:00:00 6,0 <NA>      600,00   1404,00
#  9: 2017-05-17 15:00:00 2,0 <NA>        <NA>   1404,00
# 10: 2017-05-17 16:00:00 3,0 <NA>        <NA>   1404,00
# 11: 2017-05-17 17:00:00 4,0 <NA>        <NA>   1404,00
# 12: 2017-05-17 18:00:00 8,0 <NA>        <NA>      <NA>
```

Comment: If I copy the sample data its working but my data are excel data. Also if I prepare them with the T I get an error: Fehler in `:=`(DATE, as.POSIXct(DATE, format = "%d.%m.%yT%H:%M")) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: probabay your `DT` is not a data.table, but a data.frame.. try `data.table::setDT(DT)` before other data.table-operations

Answer (score 0):

I think the tricky part is that your first data frame has the times per hour and the second dataframe has a begin and end time. Therefore you first need to create a dataframe that has the right sequence of hours, with `seq`. Then you can join each dataframe with `left_join` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
datetime <- c("17.5.17 07:00", "17.5.17 08:00", "17.5.17 09:00", "17.5.17 10:00", "17.5.17 11:00", "17.5.17 12:00", "17.5.17 13:00", "17.5.17 14:00", "17.5.17 15:00", "17.5.17 16:00", "17.5.17 17:00", "17.5.17 18:00")
PM1 <- c("5,0", "4,0", "1,0", "1,0", "2,0", "5,0", "4,0", "6,0", "2,0", "3,0", "4,0", "8,0")
df1 <- data.frame(datetime, PM1)
df1$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df1$datetime, format = "%d.%m.%y %H:%M")

df1
              datetime PM1
1  2017-05-17 07:00:00 5,0
2  2017-05-17 08:00:00 4,0
3  2017-05-17 09:00:00 1,0
4  2017-05-17 10:00:00 1,0
5  2017-05-17 11:00:00 2,0
6  2017-05-17 12:00:00 5,0
7  2017-05-17 13:00:00 4,0
8  2017-05-17 14:00:00 6,0
9  2017-05-17 15:00:00 2,0
10 2017-05-17 16:00:00 3,0
11 2017-05-17 17:00:00 4,0
12 2017-05-17 18:00:00 8,0

DATE <- c("17.5.17 00:00")
SHIP <- c("Rotterdam", "Deutschland")
In <- c("07:00", "08:00")
Out <- c("17:00", "14:00")
PAX <- c(1404, 600)
df <- data.frame(DATE, SHIP, In, Out, PAX)
df
               DATE        SHIP    In   Out  PAX
1 17.5.17 00:00   Rotterdam 07:00 17:00 1404
2 17.5.17 00:00 Deutschland 08:00 14:00  600

#Change formatting of dates
df$DATE <- gsub(" 00:00", "", df$DATE)
df$In <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$DATE, df$In, sep = " "), format = "%d.%m.%y %H:%M")
df$Out <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$DATE, df$Out, sep = " "), format = "%d.%m.%y %H:%M")

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  #Create time sequence per hour
  datetime <- seq(df$In[i], df$Out[i], by = "hour")
  SHIP <- df$SHIP[i]
  PAX <- df$PAX[i]
  #Create temp df2
  df2 <- data.frame(datetime, SHIP, PAX)
  #Left join every time
  df1 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("datetime" = "datetime"))
}

df1
              datetime PM1    SHIP.x PAX.x      SHIP.y PAX.y
1  2017-05-17 07:00:00 5,0 Rotterdam  1404        <NA>    NA
2  2017-05-17 08:00:00 4,0 Rotterdam  1404 Deutschland   600
3  2017-05-17 09:00:00 1,0 Rotterdam  1404 Deutschland   600
4  2017-05-17 10:00:00 1,0 Rotterdam  1404 Deutschland   600
5  2017-05-17 11:00:00 2,0 Rotterdam  1404 Deutschland   600
6  2017-05-17 12:00:00 5,0 Rotterdam  1404 Deutschland   600
7  2017-05-17 13:00:00 4,0 Rotterdam  1404 Deutschland   600
8  2017-05-17 14:00:00 6,0 Rotterdam  1404 Deutschland   600
9  2017-05-17 15:00:00 2,0 Rotterdam  1404        <NA>    NA
10 2017-05-17 16:00:00 3,0 Rotterdam  1404        <NA>    NA
11 2017-05-17 17:00:00 4,0 Rotterdam  1404        <NA>    NA
12 2017-05-17 18:00:00 8,0      <NA>    NA        <NA>    NA
```